# StructureMap setter injection for a property that use generics

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, structuremap

**EDIT**: Cleared up some names and made the examples easier to read.

This class:

```
public class EntranceService : IEntranceService
{
    public IMyNotifier<Entrance> Notifier { get; set; }


    public EntranceService(IRepositoryConfigDb<Entrance> repo   )
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

I want to use the Notifier property to be injected via setter injection. As you can see the Notifier uses a an interface with an open generic type, and therefore I cannot do the following:

```
x.SetAllProperties(p => p.OfType<IMyNotifier<IEntity>>());
```

StructureMap doesn't like it.
This is what the IMyNotifier looks like:

```
public interface  IMyNotifier<T> where  T : class, IEntity, new()
```

**EDIT**: This leads me having to set a rule for each and every concrete implemention from IEntity, like this:

```
x.SetAllProperties(setter => setter.OfType<IMyNotifier<Entrance>>());
x.SetAllProperties(setter => setter.OfType<IMyNotifier<Something>>());
x.SetAllProperties(setter => setter.OfType<IMyNotifier<Endpoint>>());
x.SetAllProperties(setter => setter.OfType<IMyNotifier<Interaction>>());
x.SetAllProperties(setter => setter.OfType<IMyNotifier<Queue>>());
x.SetAllProperties(setter => setter.OfType<IMyNotifier<Group>>());
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: In most cases, you should favor constructor injection over property injection. Is there a particular reason why you need to use property injection in this case?

Comment: Hello Steven, I agree but that's a separate thing. This question is specific to when defining Setter Injection.

Comment: Can someone please show me where x comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this isn't too hard.. you'll just have to use a slightly different method of looking at the properties you want to set.

```
 x.SetAllProperties(
    p=> p.TypeMatches(
           t=>t.IsInterface 
              && t.IsGenericType 
              && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyNotifier<>)
    )
 );
```

What this does is look at the property type against a predicate. So we see is it an interface, is it generic, then get the open generic and compare it to what we want to match to.